# How do I set the time of a device in Windows 10 ioT?

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 ioT.  How do I set the time of the device using C#  ?
Thanks

P.S. If not possible, how do I set the timezone ?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by [connecting remotely to your device via Powershell](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm) and running "tzutil".

**Current time zone**

TZUTIL /g

**Current time**

date

**To get a list of all available time zones**

tzutil /l

**Set time zone**

TZUTIL /s "Pakistan Standard Time"